# Numerical evaluation of the Laplace operator near the singularity points in spherical coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, harmonic-functions, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

If one had to evaluate $\Delta Y_l^m$ numerically everywhere on the unit sphere, including the singularity points $\theta = 0,\pi$, how would they do it? Let's say $Y_l^m$ is a spherical harmonic. I'm wondering if there is an "automatic" procedure that avoids this sort of problems. My operator is a bit different, but it also has similar singularities, and in general I don't know, where they're located. Thanks!

Comment: Spherical harmonics can be expressed as polynomials in $x, y, z$, assuming $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \text{const}$. See (37-42) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html)

Comment: True, but my question was related to some general operator that has singularities of the same kind as those of Laplacian in spherical coordinates. This new operator needs to act on spherical harmonics (which are not eigenfunctions anymore), and the singularities have to be worked around in some way in order to maintain accuracy. The general problem is to find the operator's eigenfunctions, and I was thinking about expanding them in spherical harmonis